# Application in Android studio is stopping automatically while debugging

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-debug, android-developer-api

There is an app which i am running on android studio in debug mode. It is running fine and it stops at the breakpoint set, but when i press F6(Step Over) after the breakpoint i.e. Step Over again and again, it will execute till the end of that function and then stops the application and the debugger. But when i press F8(Resume prog) to resume the program, it works normally and even the functions after this breakpoints are called as expected and neither the debugger nor the application stops.
Any idea why it is happening in case of F6 only and not in F8? 
Note:- Keymap is changed to Eclipse, so there is no point of shortcuts

Comment: It seems like this is a bug, see link here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200880

Answer (score -1):

in android f6 is not used for Debug please refer this key map for android studio [here](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Comment: i have changed the keymap to eclipse, so it is not default key map